# Is sarcasm lying?

Tags: halal-haram, behavior, lying

Salam is being sarcastic a form of lying? I was talking to my brother and he said something and I was like "oh sorry, my bad" in a sarcastic way, does that count as lying? And also when they know you are being sarcastic/joking is that okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not the same.

A lie is something said/written which is false and the speaker/writer knows that it is not true.

What you said is not nice, but it is not a lie.